# How to create a Model in Yii2 with increase of table every month

Tags: php, database, model, yii2, frameworks

I have an attendance system which table is increased every month. Like for the month of April 2020 the name of table is att202004, May 2020 the name of table is att202005 and etc. As you know the model name and naming file in Yii2 is static and I have to create new model every month. How to create a model that handle all months of the attendance. TQ

Comment: create console method which will be performed at the begging or the end of each month, and in action use file functions to create needed models or edit needed line of code in the model. Then create a cron job and call this action at the end of each month.

Comment: why are you creating a new table every month ?

Comment: It's not me. The bio-metric system creates new table every month. I just want develop an application that read directly from the system.

Comment: ok and you want, if today is 30th april and tomorrow is 1st May you want the model to be automatically switch to the new table and leave the previous one? when it is 1st May

Comment: you could use use gii  for create the model ..or a  php  function for create a php file for model ..

Comment: The framework requirement need you to create new model every month. I don't want to do that because it's like manual work. In case I forget to create new model for the new month, system will get error. I just want to create a model once for the whole existing tables and the whole new coming tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to have models for limited amount of tables, for example only for current month you can use fact, that the table name is defined in static method so you can have dynamic table name.

```php
class CurrentMonth extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'att' . date('Ym');
    }

    //... other definitions
}
```

If you need to create model for each existing table you can use autoloader to create classes dynamically.

Implement and register your autoloader in autoload.php. In this example i will assume that tables are named like `att202005` and created models will be `\app\dynamicModels\Att202005`.

```
class DynamicModelFactory
{
    protected static function classBasename($class)
    {
        $split = explode('\\', $class);
        return end($split);
    }

    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        if (strpos($class, 'app\\dynamicModels') !== 0) {
            //skip if the class is not in app\dynamicModels namespace
            return;
        }

        $className = static::classBasename($class);
        //get table name from class name by converting the first letter to lower case
        $tableName = lcfirst($className);

        $template = static::template();
        $template = str_replace(
            ['{className}', '{tableName}'],
            [$className, $tableName],
            $template
        );

        eval($template);
    }

    protected static function template()
    {
        $code = <<<CODE
namespace app\dynamicModels;

class {className} extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{tableName}';
    }
}
CODE;
        return $code;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(['DynamicModelFactory', 'autoload']);
```

Then modify your index.php to require this autoload skript before the Yii autoloader:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php'; // <- this is our autoloader
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
```

If you need more complex code for the model class you can put it into independent file and load it with `file_get_content` instead of putting in directly in autoloader class. You can also add code, that would check the existence of table in DB before creating the model class if you want.

Comment: Thanks. This solved a part of the problem. It will be problem is accessing more than 1 table in one time example creating 1 year report of attendance.

Comment: @jai3232 for things like 1 year report it might be better to use union query together with [`yii\data\SqlDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider). If you need multiple models you can use the autoload approach from my answer. You can't have one active record model that would refer multiple tables at same time.